# recover data by passing through different components angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have three 3 components :

component1.html

```
<p>poster</p>
```

component1.ts

```
data:Data

ngOnInit() {
this.getData();
}
getData(){
this.component1Service.data().subsribe(data => {
this.data = data;
this.component1Service.setData(this.data);
  });
 }
}
```

component1Service.ts

```
private dataSubject: BehaviorSubject<Data> = new BehaviorSubject<Data>(null);
data$: Observable<Data> = this.dataSubject.asObservable();
data() {
 return this.http.getData();
}
setData(data: Data) {
 this.dataSubject.next(data);
}
```

component2.html

```
<component1></component1>
<p>{{data}}</p>
<component3></component3>
```

component2.ts

```
data: Data;
ngOnInit() {
this.component1Service.data$.subscribe(data => {
this.data = data
}
```

component3.html

```
 <p>{{data}}</p>
```

component3.ts

```
data: Data;
ngOnInit() {
this.component1Service.data$.subscribe(data => {
this.data = data
}
```

when I'm on the component 2 page, in component 3 this.data is undefined, I don't know why? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: If you put a `console.log` after `this.data = data` can you see `this.data` populated? I think it's a problem of change detection

Comment: he shows me undefined

Comment: However in component 2, it works well

Comment: It's strange that your observable fires when it's still undefined but not after... Are you able to reproduce the issue on a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)?

Comment: <component1></component1><p>{{data}}</p>
<component3></component3>